# Deploy TCK Kapacitor conf

Tags: variables, ansible, kapacitor

I need to deploy TICK. 
How do you use variables in **kapacitor.conf**?

EX:   `username = "{{ admin }}"`

I have a **kapacitor.conf** with variables to replace, and I have a file **default.yml** with variables.

**Kapacitor.conf**

```
username = "{{ admin }}"
password = "{{ admin_password }}"
```

**default.yml**

```
---
admin: admin
admin_password: admin
```

Comment: What does the playbook look like that is deploying this file?

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html). Given the variables

```
> cat default.yml 
username: admin
password: admin_password
```

the playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - default.yml
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: Kapacitor.conf
        regexp: "^{{ item.key }}:"
        line: "{{ item.key }}:{{ item.value }}"
        create: yes
      loop:
        - {key: 'admin', value: "{{ username }}"}
        - {key: 'admin_password', value: "{{ password }}"}
```

gives:

```
> cat Kapacitor.conf 
admin:admin
admin_password:admin_password
```

next (for some first) option would be [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html).